# Zsh alias complex string quote escaping

Tags: zsh

I am trying to define an alias (`alias gsl="..."`) for the following command, but can't get the escaped quotes right.

`git stash list | awk -F: '{ print "\n\n\n\n"; print $0; print "\n\n"; system("git stash show -p " $1); }'`

Any tips on how to escape the quote to define the alias correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
 alias gsl="git stash list | awk -F: '{ print \"\\n\\n\\n\\n\"; print \$0; print \"\\n\\n\"; system(\"git stash show -p \" \$1); }' "
```

Rules:

- escape double-quotes in double-quotes
- escape $'s in double-quotes
- escape the escape character `\`
- don't escape the single-quotes -- you don't want a literal single-quote, but just group the awk command into one parameter